# How to use two types in list List<T,T2>

Tags: c#, generics

Can we use two different type argument in `List <T>`  or add one more argument inside the class type?

For example:

```
public class ClassA
{
 public int a {get;set;}
 public int b {get;set;}
}
```

I need on more properties in the List without editing ClassA

```
public string c {get;set;}

public List<ClassA, c> list = new List<ClassA, c>
```

I should able to access c inside the List

```
item[0].a
item[0].b
item[0].c
```

Comment: You can't that's not how Lists work or what they are for.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a recent C# version you can use tuples:

```
public List<(ClassA, string)> list = new List<(ClassA, string)>
```

You can also name them

```
public List<(ClassA a, string c)> list = new List<(ClassA a, string c)>
```

But you can’t access anything inside ClassA directly, you’ll have to go with the first object’s name.

Comment: Tuples aren't restricted to recent versions, just the Value Tuple and name tuples, which makes them much nicer. Old versions of C# still have Tuple<T1,T2,...>
The other option is also to create a new wrapper class, which is correct depends on your scenario. If you find your self passing lots of tuple types around, a class is probably going to be better

Comment: @Dave True, I omitted `Tuple<>` due to it not really being in any way better than creating a new class, which I assume they already have considered. And I agree on the overuse of tuples, whatever the type.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<String,ClassA> myDictionary= New Dictionary<String,ClassA>();

Foreach(var k in myDictionary.Keys)
Debug.WriteLine(myDictionary[k]);// accesses (Value) ClassA objects
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for help guys it was a great help. 
but in my cod i used new class:

```
public classB 
{
     public classA cA {get;set;}
     public str c {get;set;}
}

List<B>  i can access any data i need it.
```

Comment: So you asked the question how do I do x and then answered it yourself saying I decided to do y. Essentially this answer doesn't answer you own question.